# install postgres on linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos5

i want to install postgres on centos 5.3 via rpm, i execute command

```
 rpm -ihv postgres-9.0.3-1.i386.openscg.rpm
```

shows error

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libperl.so is needed by postgres-9.0-9.0.3-1.i386
```

it seems that it required perl (i think), but perl version 5.8 is already install

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got solution

by installing

```
rpm -hiv ../inc/postgresql-8.1.23-1.el5_6.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -hiv ../inc/postgresql-server-8.1.23-1.el5_6.1.x86_64.rpm
```